# Can Spring Boot Actuator not use server.context-path?

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a way to get actuator to not use the server.contextPath?

```
server: 
  contextPath: /myApp/
management:
  context-path: /
```

I want actuator stay with the root context.

```
localhost:8080/myApp
localhost:8080/health
```

Comment: Could you please set the management port(Different port) and try to hit with management-context-path...

Comment: Also which version of spring-boot are you using? I remember in the past we had this issue but later they fixed it...

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4401 You can refer this link for any doubt...Kindly let us know for any more issues...

Comment: is my answer was helpful to you ?